# Are native tokens divisible?

Tags: native-assets

If I mint a `NEAT` token, can I send .5 `NEAT` to someone or do I have to send a whole 1 `NEAT`?

Comment: Under the hood at the ledger levels there's no concept of floats for native tokens. To have a partial token (like having a partial ada), there needs to be some metadata option that says 1000 X token is really 1 X. But this is just a end user client abstraction layer. If you mint 1 of a token, that isn't divisible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no support for decimal places of native tokens on Cardano.

Comment: The data type is an Integer as defined in Haskell, and has an unbounded theoretical limit.

Answer (score 3):

Although, I tried finding an explicit reference in the [source](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/28b934fbab1994704bdccdcc5f88b13fc9680fe6/cardano-cli/src/Cardano/CLI/Run/Friendly.hs#L121) my Haskell knowledge is awful and I couldn't find the data type associated with the [--mint](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/28b934fbab1994704bdccdcc5f88b13fc9680fe6/doc/reference/shelley-genesis.md) parameter for the CLI.

My 99.999% gut instinct tells me that it's based on a `Number` type, which can be an arbitrary floating point value. In which case, yes, you could subdivide.

I see no reason they would limit the token API to only support integer values (even though integers are generally safer for financial transactions since operations don't produce rounding errors).

Comment: The reason why there is no support for decimal places on Cardano right now, is because they are not on-chain and therefore could not be verified by hardware wallets. This might change in the future with Plutus smart contacts.